# Show that $\omega\mapsto\int_a^bX_t(\omega)\;dt$ is measurable, for a real-valued and continuous stochastic process $X$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\operatorname{P})$ be a probability space
- $X=(X_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a real-valued and continuous stochastic process on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\operatorname{P})$
- $0\le a<b$

I want to show, that $$\Omega\to\mathbb{R}\;,\;\;\;\omega\mapsto\int_a^bX_t(\omega)\;dt$$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable.

---

Since $X$ is continuous, for all $\omega\in\Omega$ $$X(\;\cdot\;,\omega):[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}\;,\;\;\;t\mapsto X_t(\omega)$$ is $\mathcal{B}\left([0,\infty)\right)$-measurable (where $\mathcal{B}(E)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on a topological space $E$). Thus, $$\mu(A):=\int_AX(\;\cdot\;,\omega)\;d\lambda\;\;\;\text{for }A\in\mathcal{B}\left([0,\infty)\right)\tag{1}$$ is a measure (measure with density $X(\;\cdot\;,\omega)$ with respect to $\left.\lambda\right|_{[0,\infty)}$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$).

However, I don't know how I need to proceed. Maybe, it's wrong to consider $(1)$. What do we need to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By definition, the Riemann-integral of a function $f$ equals

$$\int_a^b f(t) \, dt = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^n f(t_j^n) (t_j^n-t_{j-1}^n)$$

where $\Pi^n = \{a=t_0^n < \ldots < t_n^n = b\}$ denotes a partition of the interval $[a,b]$ and the mesh size $|\Pi^n|$ converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. Consequently,

$$\int_a^b X(t)(\omega) \, dt = \lim_{n \to \infty} \underbrace{\sum_{j=1}^n X(t_j^n,\omega)(t_{j}^n-t_{j-1}^n)}_{\mathcal{A}-\text{measurable}}$$

is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable as a pointwise limit of $\mathcal{A}$-measurable functions.

Comment: So, we should be able to conclude that $$\omega \mapsto \int_0^\infty X_t(\omega)\;dt=\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_0^bX_t(\omega)\;dt$$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable too, right?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Yeah, sure, whenever the limit exists... it is measurable as a pointwise limit of measurable functions. (Note however that in this case the integral at the left-hand side is an improper Riemann integral, not a Lebesgue integral.)

Comment: Is your note important for the measurability?

Comment: What I still don't understand: Why is $X(t_j^n)(t_j^n-t_{j-1}^n)$ measurable wrt $\mathcal{A}$? It's a constant, isn't it? So, it is measurable wrt any $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Ah, sorry, my mistake. No, it doesn't matter (and actually, as long as you assume that $\int_0^{\infty} |X_t| \, dt < \infty$, it doesn't matter whether it is Riemann or Lebesgue integral.)

Comment: No, it's not a constant. $X(t_j^n)(t_j^n-t_{j-1}^n)$ still depends on $\omega$: $$\omega \mapsto X(t_j^n,\omega) (t_j^n-t_{j-1}^n).$$ ($X(t)$ is just another way to write $X_t$, i.e. $X(t,\omega) = X_t(\omega)$.)

Comment: Moreover, shouldn't we state that $$\int_a^bf(x)\;dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n(t_i^n-t_{i-1}^n)\inf f\left(\left[t_{i-1}^n,t_i^n\right)\right)$$ or is that not important?

Comment: [Related to the first question] Sorry, your notation confused me ;)

Comment: @0xbadf00d I see; sorry; I'm so used to it that I don't even think about it. Concerning your other question: Since $X(\cdot,\omega)$ is continuous, it doesn't matter; we have $$\int_a^b f(x) \, dx = \lim_n \sum_i (t_i^n-t_{i-1}^n) f(\xi_i^n)$$ for any intermediate point $\xi_i^n \in [t_{i-1}^n,t_i^n]$ and any continuous function $f$.

Comment: Is $a<b$ important. I don't think so. It should work with any interval. Am I right?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Yes, it works with any interval.

Comment: Would we get problems, if we would use $\inf f([t_{i-1}^n,t_i^n))$ instead? I know that $$\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}X_n$$ is measurable if all $X_n$ are measurable. However, here, we would deal with uncountable many random variables.

Comment: @0xbadf00d If $f$ is continuous, then $$\inf_{t \in [t_{i-1}^n,t_i^n]} f(t) = \inf_{t \in [t_{i-1}^n,t_i^n] \cap \mathbb{Q}} f(t),$$ this implies that $\omega \mapsto \inf_{t \in [t_{i-1}^n,t_i^n]} X_t(\omega)$ is measurable.

Comment: How can we prove that? I think it's a general statement about continuous functions.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Actually, it follows directly from the definition of continuity. However, since ongoing discussions in comments are not approved in this community, please ask a new question if you do not know how to prove this.