# Measurability of an integral

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Let $\{X_t\}_{t\ge 0}$ be an adapted $\mathbb{R}$-valued stochastic process on some filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t\ge 0},\mathbb{P}\}$ such that for each $\omega\in\Omega$ and $t\ge 0$ the integral $\int_0^t X_s(\omega)ds$ exists (Lebesgue integration). Why is this integral $\mathcal{F}$-$\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable (as a function in $\omega$) if the process $X$ is progressively measurable? Does someone know how to prove this?

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1278845/

Comment: @saz: Unfortunately, my process $X$ needs not to be continuous whence the Riemann approach could fail to work. I have also tried to use the construction of the Lebesgue integral via simple functions but since I don't know an explicit representation of these approximants I wasn't able to conclude measurability of the integral, yet.

Comment: Can we show that $(s,\omega) \mapsto X_s(\omega)$ is measurable from $\mathfrak B \times \mathcal F$ to $\mathfrak B$ ??  Then we could probably apply Fubini's theorem.  I guess we would need hypothesis $\mathbb E \int_0^t |X_s(\omega)|\,ds < +\infty$ for this approach?

Comment: @JohnSmith It is not of importance whether the process is continuous; the argumentation in the linked question works for any progressively measurable process such that $\omega \mapsto \int_0^t X_s(\omega) \, ds$ is well-defined.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

**example**
Without assuming some "joint" measurability of $X_t(\omega)$ in $t$ and $\omega$ you are out of luck.

We use the Continuum Hypothesis.  There is a set
$A \subseteq [0,1] \times [0,1]$
such that:

$\qquad$For each $t \in [0,1]$,$\qquad \{\omega \in [0,1] : (t,\omega) \in A\}$ is countable,

$\qquad$For each $\omega \in [0,1]$,$\qquad \{t \in [0,1] : (t,\omega) \in A\}$ is co-countable.

> On the space $[0,\omega_1)$ of countable ordinals, the set $\{(s,t) : s > t\}$ has these properties; transfer it to $\mathbb R$ by CH.

Now let $\Omega = [0,1]$, $\mathcal F = \mathfrak B$, the Borel sets in $[0,1]$.  Also let $\mathcal F_t = \mathcal F$ for all $t \in [0,1]$.

Let $\mathbb P$ be Lebesgue measure.

Choose a non-measurable function $h : [0,1] \to [0,1]$.

Define:
$$
X_t(\omega) := \begin{cases}
h(\omega),\qquad (t,\omega) \in A
\\
0,\qquad (t,\omega) \not\in A
\end{cases}
$$
Now for each fixed $t$, we have $X_t(\omega)=0$ except for countably many $\omega$, so $X_t$ is $\mathcal F_t$-measurable.  [I hope this is your definiton of "adapted $\mathbb R$-valued stochastic process".]

On the other hand, for each fixed $\omega$, we have $X_t(\omega)=h(\omega)$ except for countably many $t$.  Integrating a function that is constant a.e., we get
$$
\int_0^1 X_t(\omega)\;dt = h(\omega)
$$
which is a non-measurable function of $\omega$.